# Solve exponential inequation $(e^x)^2-e^x.e^1 - e^x + e < 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, factoring

I have the equation $e^{2x}-e^{x+1} - e^x + e < 0$.
I solved that equation until here:

$(e^x)^2-e^x.e^1 - e^x + e < 0$

$y=e^x$

$(y)^2-y.e^1 - y + e < 0$

$y^2-y.e - y + e < 0$

But from here i am not able to solve through a quadratic equation. How can i solve that?

Comment: What's stopping you from finding the roots of the quadratic?

Comment: you mean $y=e^x$ and not $2^x$

Comment: @Isham It's got to be

Comment: $y^2+(-e-1)y+e=0$ for a start. Quadratic formula?

Comment: Product of roots $+e$; sum is $e+1$  any guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$e^x(e^x-e)-(e^x-e)<0$$ or
$$(e^x-e)(e^x-1)<0$$ or
$$1<e^x<e$$ or
$$0<x<1.$$
Your quadratic inequality we can solve by the same way:
$$y^2-ey-y+e<0$$ or
$$y(y-e)-(y-e)<0$$ or
$$(y-1)(y-e)<0$$ or
$$1<y<e.$$